# When to free string pointer?

Tags: c, linux

I have a macro defined as below. Also in my program, I need to print out error message in the 2 styles:

1. `PRINT_ERR("This is Error!");`
2. Use asprint to construct a log string then print it out:

```
 char *log = NULL;
 int age = 0;
 asprintf(&log, "error: %s on: %d", "Name", age);
 PRINT_ERR(log);
```

With below macro definition, Style #1 will throw exceptions.
So, in the macro definition, how do I figure out in which condition, I need to free the string "y"?

```
#define PRINT_LOG(x, y) { \
    printf ( "%s: %s\n", x, y);\
    free(y);\    //how do I know "y" is a pointer, or a string like this "string"?
}

#define PRINT_ERR(y) { PRINT_LOG ("ERR ", y) }
```

Comment: #1 couldn't be freed anyways, since that string isn't allocated dynamically. it's compiled into the executable and will always be in memory.

Comment: So you really want to print "ERR : error: Name on: 0"? (seems awkward...)

Comment: "how do I know "y" is a pointer, or a string like this "string"" – you don't. And you *shouldn't need to know.* Design your program in a way that you don't need to know whether your string is a literal or dynamically-allocated.

Comment: @jweyrich yeah, but string literals (what Marc B was talking about) aren't.

Comment: There is no reliable way for the macro to determine whether one of its arguments is a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory.  You need to pass an argument that tells it, or else use different macros for the different cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use two different macros - along the lines below?

```
#define PRINT_ERR(y) ....

#define PRINT_ERR_FREE(y) \
    do { \
        PRINT_ERR(y);  \
        free(y);\
     } while (0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your macro/function/whatever **cannot distinguish between string literals and dynamically allocated strings**, therefore, you can't always `free()` the string argument, because string literals cannot be `free`'d.

A simple solution would be to write a **variadic function** (or a variadic macro, if you still prefer):

```
void LOG(const char* format, ...)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);
    int ret = vasprintf(&str, format, argptr);
    if (ret == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    va_end(argptr);
    PRINT_ERR(str);
    free(str);
}
```